# Minimal drop size

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, surface-tension

I am trying to do something that requires very high precision, so I got stuck in a question:
What is the lower bound of a size of a water droplet (and what is the equation, I want to use different chemicals in general) that I will be able to push of a syringe, so it would actually drop?
A more accurate way of  asking it - 
How much force will push how much liquid from a pipe with radius r?
What weight of drop can not be held by surface tension on said pipe?

I am not a physics expert, so if I'm asking something that should be obvious, apologies, I've looked and couldn't find an answer.